# Parse Drools rule file with Java regex

Tags: java, regex, drools

I'm interested in parsing a Drools rule file using regular expressions.
Having a string with the content of the whole .drl file, I'd like to have 4 substrings:

1. A substring with the content of `<name>`
2. A substring with the content of `<attribute>`
3. A substring with the content of `<conditional element>`
4. A substring with the content of `<action>`

A Drools rule has the following structure, according to the [official documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.0.1.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#d0e6601):

```
rule "<name>"
    <attribute>*
when
    <conditional element>*
then
    <action>*
end
```

I've tried using this pattern, but it hasn't worked well:

```
^rule"(.|\n|\r|\t)+"(.|\n|\r|\t)+\bwhen\b(.|\n|\r|\t)+\bthen\b(.|\n|\r|\t)+\bend\b?$
```

Does anyone have an idea of how could I proceed?

Comment: `.` can match anything except line separators. If you want `.` to also match them so instead of `.|\n|\r|\t` to simple use `.`, add `Pattern.DOTALL` flag to your regex `(?s)`. Also `but it hasn't worked well` is not best way to describe problem you are facing with this regex. Can you explain how you used this regex, what was your input, output and expected output? I suspect problems with `(.|\n|\r|\t)+` which is greedy and can match anything.

Comment: I'd consider taking a look at javacc for any sort of complex parsing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost got it. This work:

```
^rule\s+\"(.|\n|\r|\t)+\"(.|\n|\r|\t)+\bwhen\b(.|\n|\r|\t)+\bthen\b(.|\n|\r|\t)+\bend\b?$
```

Another solution:

```
^\s*rule\s+\"([^\"]+)\"[\s\S]+\s+when\s+([\s\S]+)\s+then\s+([\s\S]+)\send\s*$
```

Note: You missed the space and " -> \"

Tips:

- You can use \s for white space charcters.
- [^\"] for all non " character.
- [\s\S] for all characters.
- \b stop at `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. \s+ stop at any non-whitespace character. It is just an extra precaution if any attribute start with a special character.
- Use a program like Rad Software Regular Expression Designer. That will dramatically simplify editing and testing your regex code.

Answer (score 6):

I know your question is about regexp, but I would strongly advise against using it. There are way too many cases that will fail with your regexp... for instance, rule names that are a single word don't need "", rule keyword does not need to be the first thing in the line, etc...

```
/*this is a comment on the start of the line*/ rule X...
```

Instead of regexp, just use the DrlParser directly and it will give you all the information you need:

```
String drl = "package foo \n"
                 + "declare Bean1 \n"
                 + "field1: java.math.BigDecimal \n"
                 + "end \n"
                 + "rule bigdecimal\n"
                 + "when \n"
                 + "Bean1( field1 == 0B ) \n"
                 + "then \n"
                 + "end";

DrlParser parser = new DrlParser(LanguageLevelOption.DRL6);
PackageDescr pkgDescr = parser.parse( null, drl );
```

PackageDescr.getRules() will give you all the RuleDescr in the file, each RuleDescr has a getName() to give you the rule name, etc. All type safe, no edge cases, etc.

Comment: I have similar code. The only bit changes is Rule conditions in when block. I am getting inconsistent behaviour. If I use str[startsWith], parser throws error 101 - mismatched input 'str' in rule. If I use == condition, parser works. Also it then starts working for str[startsWith] condition. Not sure why this is happening.

Comment: It is great. Thank you very much :)